# Finding ward level administrative boundary data for india?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, census, india

In the census 2011 data there is data at ward level.
Is it possible to get shapefiles at that level? (paid/free)
Please don't refer me to GADM , which is at taluk level.
I want at least 2011.

How good is [google geocoding api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) with respect to this?
Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: I think this is a question best researched/asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.  If you decide to leave it here can you include links to the previous Q&As that you have discounted as being not useful for your purposes, please?

Comment: Is there a direct way to transfer it open data exchange

Comment: Yes - I can migrate it but I strongly recommend that you review their help and  [edit] it there to ensure that meets that site's standards.

Answer (score 2):

Village level boundaries for many parts of India is available [here](https://archive.org/details/IndiaVillageBoundaries) as JSON files as per 2001 census data

Comment: can you refer me to the official website ,if possible?

Comment: I don't know which is original website. See this github  [page](https://github.com/datameet/indian_village_boundaries)

Comment: Is it possible to get for some states atleast,from official website?

Comment: One can get wms service from Bhuvan. Try contacting Survey of India

Comment: Will that be 2011 or 2001?

Comment: I don't know about bhuvan. Survey of India will have 2011 census data

Comment: Can you give me the link or contact?

Comment: Link for survey of India [home page](http://www.surveyofindia.gov.in/). Bhuvan wms link for QGIS is [this](http://bhuvan5.nrsc.gov.in/bhuvan/wms).

Comment: How good will it be to use 2001 gis maps for 2011 census data?

Comment: [Here](http://censusindia.gov.in/2011-common/maps.html) census 2011 jpeg images upto district level is available, you can use this for comparing with 2001 data.